# Why did the US invade Cuba in such a weak manner?

Tags: united-states, cuba, invasion

I've been reading about the US's history with Cuba following the recent death of Castro, and the failure of the Bay of Pigs seems very odd to me. The only reason I can think of for carrying out such a weak and chancy invasion is that Eisenhower must have believed he could keep the US involvement a secret. Otherwise, I don't see the sense in attempting an overthrow only to fail and be internationally embarrassed. He had the power to eliminate Castro with a proper invasion, I just don't understand why he would choose to do it half way rather than go in with full force if he was going to do it at all.

Can someone explain?

I read the Wikipedia article on this and learned what happened, but not why they did it the way they did.

Comment: Given that President Eisenhower wasn't involved in the actual decision to go ahead, this question rather misses the actual history of the Bay of Pigs attempted invasion.

Comment: Cuba was a Soviet client (cf. the Cuban Missile Crisis a few years later) so a full invasion by US forces with flying colours was probably never an option. However, takeover by Cuban exiles acting as proxies could give the US government just enough plausible deniability of direct involvement. Presumably, the exiles also underestimated and misrepresented the difficulty of the whole enterprise.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Afair, he did authorize the planning.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg That is irrelevant, since Ike was (unlike most presidents) intimately familiar with the difference between planning and execution of  military operations. I've been involved in work on a variety of Op Plans and Contingency plans that never got executed.  Simply having a plan doesn't mean anything.  Suggest you look up Op Plan Blue Spoon in re Panama/Noriega.  Sure, it was a plan, but it was a fool's errand.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg  There is a recent bio of Ike that I can't seem to find.  Read it a couple of years ago.  It went into some detail for why Ike approved planning but was not near to an execution condition.  Will post the book's name when I find it.

Comment: IMO there is a difference between mere "planning" and actually training Brigade 2506 in Guatemala. Ike authorized the latter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An invasion by US armed forces would have worked, but would also have been deeply illegal, since it would have been a war of aggression. It would also likely have precipitated a war with the Soviet Union, and Cuba wasn't worth that risk.

The plan seems to have started as one for a counter-revolution within Cuba with outside support, and been expanded into a plan for overt military action without that being properly thought through. The forces that landed, composed of Cuban exiles, were too small for the job and didn't have enough supplies or support. They also assumed they would have support from the population, but actually, most of them were pro-Castro.

Wikipedia's summary of the [CIA internal report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bay_of_Pigs_Invasion#C.I.A._report) on the fiasco covers the matter reasonably well.

Comment: Any US invasion of Cuba to protect life and property of American Citizens of Cuba would have been legal. Certainly no one complained about Grenada in 1983 or Haiti during the Clintons up to the present day. I think one answer is the oddity of establlishing a Communist Dictatorship on a Carribbean Island.

Comment: Haiti was authorised by the UN Security Council. Grenada was not, and was condemned by the UN General Assembly as "A flagrant violation of international law." The Eisenhower and Kennedy administrations may well have been a lot more concerned about that than the Reagan administration was in 1983.

Comment: @JohnDallman The UN was not the only body to condemn the invasion of Grenada. At the time the Queen was head of state there, and the White House significantly forgot to consult Downing Street in advance. As a result Reagan got an earful down the phone from Margaret Thatcher!